# Html form field - remove spaces Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to remove any spaces in a form field, the "onblur" solutions when i have googled it are not working for me. Is it anything to do with browser compatability? Im using IE10

Comment: You should show the code you've already tried.

Comment: Sorry :/ im new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this between your head tags:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function removeSpaces(string) {
return string.split(' ').join('');
}
</script>
```

And this in your input tag:

```
onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function to remove spaces, try it:

```
function removeSpaces(ch)
{
   ch = ch.replace(/\ /g,"");
   return ch;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use via `jquery` trim function.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/